# Random effects estimation error with plm package due to negative variance

Tags: r, plm, random-effects

I'm trying to estimate a panel data model with random effects Swamy and Arora transformation on market share data of tourism destinations. Please find attached the dataset in https://github.com/Joseperles/Statistical-questions

The model is estimated according the following code:

```
random<-plm(ld_Share~ld_Gdp+ld_Gdppc+ld_Gkf+ld_Cpi+ld_Fdi+ld_Exrate,
 data=Panel, index=c("Country", "obs"), model="random")
```

However I get this error message:

> Error in swar(object, data, effect) :
> the estimated variance of the individual effect is negative

However, when I use Gretl, EViews or Stata to compare, I get an estimation for this model (the same output in all of them based on GLS estimation). (Please, find the output from this econometric packages at the same web adress).

With fixed effect or pooled ols I also get the same estimations with plm and all other softwares.

Somebody knows what could be the problem and if there is a possbility to reproduce this output of EViews or Stata for the random model (the same estimation procedure) with the plm R-package?

Comment: Looking for R forums I have found this link https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help//2013-January/344628.html that explains the reasons for this plm behaviour. However, nobody knows any R package that estimates the random effect changing negative components of variance by zero as does Stata, Eviews or Gretl?

Comment: Sorry but were you able to find a solution to this? I have the same issue with my data,,,

Comment: Have a look at the newest `plm` (v1.5-xx) where the error estimation has been rewritten. The estimated indiviudal variance is still negative but now you get an output for the estimates. However, the estimation might differ because STATA uses by default a slightly different estimation for random effects compared to R/plm. About negative variance estimates in random effects models in general, see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176827/error-in-plm-random-effects-swamy-arora-swar-estimator-with-lagged-dependent/181444#181444