# R plm package - error when trying to fit a random effect

Tags: r, panel-data, plm, random-effects

When I try to fit the following random effect on a panel data:

```
df<-read.csv("http://josejesus.info/Depen/panel.csv")
library(plm)
panel<-pdata.frame(df,c("state","year"))
plm(v3~v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12,data=panel,effect="twoways",model="random")
```

I get the following error:

> Error in if (sigma2$time < 0) warning("the estimated variance of the time effect is negative") : 
>     missing value where  TRUE/FALSE needed.

But if I suppress the last variable `v12` I get a result but with a  warning about the negative time variance.

Can someone help me to understand what is going on?

Comment: Did you check these answers: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186400/negative-variance-random-effects-model , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31050744/random-effects-estimation-error-with-plm-package-due-to-negative-variance, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176827/error-in-plm-random-effects-swamy-arora-swar-estimator-with-lagged-dependent/181444#181444 ?

Comment: @felix, I had seen the second one but the first one was more helpful in my case. Thanks.

Comment: Should be fixed in the current development version of plm.